# How can you update/destroy one embed document that is inside of all documents on a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

My application model allows Patients to have CustomFields. All patients have the same customs fields. Customs fields are embedded in the Patient document. I should be able to add, update and remove custom fields and such actions are extended to all patients.

```
class Patient
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :custom_fields, as: :customizable_field

  def self.add_custom_field_to_all_patients(custom_field)
    Patient.all.add_to_set(:custom_fields, custom_field.as_document)
  end

  def self.update_custom_field_on_all_patients(custom_field)       
    Patient.all.each { |patient| patient.update_custom_field(custom_field) }
  end

  def update_custom_field(custom_field)
    self.custom_fields.find(custom_field).update_attributes({ name: custom_field.name, show_on_table: custom_field.show_on_table } )
  end

  def self.destroy_custom_field_on_all_patients(custom_field)
    Patient.all.each { |patient| patient.remove_custom_field(custom_field) }
  end    

  def remove_custom_field(custom_field)
    self.custom_fields.find(custom_field).destroy
  end
end

class CustomField
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name,          type: String
  field :model,         type: Symbol
  field :value,         type: String
  field :show_on_table, type: Boolean, default: false

  embedded_in :customizable_field, polymorphic: true
end
```

All pacients have the same customs fields embedded in. Adding a custom field works very well. My doubt is about updating and destroying.

This works, but it is slow. It makes a query for each pacient. Ideally I would just be able to say to MongoDB 'update the document with *id:* that is embedded in the array *custom_fields* for all documents in the *Patient* collection'. Idem for destroy.

How can I do this in Mongoid?

I am using Mongoid 3.1.0 & Rails 3.2.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way you can do that with a good efficiency with embedded documents.

Maybe you should consider having a referenced relationship between your models, so that you can use the `delete_all` and `update_all` methods on the collection.